# Add error in existing errors while validating object through hapi/joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
              Id: Joi.number().required(),
              CustomerName: Joi.string()
                .trim()
                .required()
                .when('$isInValidCustomer', {
                  is: true,
                  then: //Add some error in existing error block,
                }),
               BankName: Joi.string().trim(),
            });

const custDetail = {
Id: 2,
CustomerName: 'xyz'
BankName: ''
};

const schemaOptions = {
              abortEarly: false,
              context: {
                isInValidCustomer: true,
              },
            };

const valError = schema.validate(custDetail, schemaOptions);
```

So, now when I validate 'custDetail' object I want following 2 errors: 
 - CustomerName error because 'isInValidCustomer' is true
 - BankName is required

I am not able to append error for CustomerName in existing error object. If I use '.error()' then just get single error corresponding to 'CustomerName' else just getting error for BankName.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using custom function.

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
              Id: Joi.number().required(),
              CustomerName: Joi.string()
                .trim()
                .required()
                .when('$isInValidCustomer', {
                  is: true,
                  then: Joi.any().custom(() => {
                    throw new Error('Invalid Customer');
                    }),
                }),
               BankName: Joi.string().trim(),
            });
```